# Локальная сеть

Tags: сеть

Как настроить локальную сеть кабинета информатики? Настройка на интернет с компьютеров уже есть!

Comment: А поточнее? Я так понимаю, компы уже объединены в ЛВС, интернет есть, компьютеры в сети друг друга видят. Чего еще изволите?

Comment: Как ответить на такой вопрос?Что должно получится ? Какие задачи поставлены в плане функционала?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, у нас есть схожие задачи. Правда я сеть в классе уже настроил :) Задачи, правда, могут быть разными: у нас что-то вроде одноранговой сети, но сервера с хранилищем пользовательских профилей нет. Поэтому описываю свой опыт.

1. Чтобы компьютеры сообщались между собой, действительно необходимо каждому прописать свой IP адрес (если, конечно, нет строгого условия динамического выделения этих адресов от провайдера или еще кого). Рекомендую учительскому компьютеру IP дать, оканчивающийся на 0, а остальные - с номерами, соответственно каждого компьютера в классе.
2. Для контроля доступа и предотвращения "левых" хождений по сети, настройте каждый компьютер выходить во внешнюю сеть через учительский. На учительский можно поставить Squid (для оптимизации и контроля выхода в сеть) и bind (особенно, если если внешний канал тощий). Можно так же на учительский поставить ftp сервер (типа vsftpd) и прокси (вроде Apache). Прокси есть смысл ставить, если хотите развернуть сайт в локальном классе :) Разумеется все ученические компы надо настроить ходить через учительский: настройки броузера, nameservers (если bind поставили) и т.п.
3. Настройте на каждом ученическом компьютере ftp доступ к нему и sshd - чтобы не бегать по классу, а работать с учительского места. Очень удобно - можно нарушителям даже комп сразу отрубать :)
4. Ученики бывают разные. У нас, например, любят менять всякие настройки, менять фон, шрифты и т.п. или удалять апплеты из кде. Чтобы запретить удалять все с рабочего стола, можно оформить рабочий стол в нужном виде и поставить запрет по правам на запись в папку /home/school/desktop (school - имя логина для учеников). Я сделал так: иконки нужных ученикам программ вынес на экран, а для ученических файлов создал на рабочем столе линки на папки из Documents "7-й класс", "8-й класс" и т.п.
5. В случае с KDE (возможно и в других системах) есть смысл зафиксировать рабочий стол и заблокировать панель меню (запретить изменения). Правда в некоторых случаях это не сильно помогает, но в большинстве вполне способно остановить злоумышленника :) Думаю, что можно сделать копирование "стандартных" (точнее оформленных вами как стандартные) настроек для их восстановления при загрузке, но с этим есть некоторые проблемы (KDE не всегда на это реагирует адекватно). Разбираюсь еще.
6. Самбу тоже можно настроить. Но у меня с ней возникли проблемы, поэтому пока не делюсь опытом. В принципе, можно обойтись и без нее (если нет огромной потребности) :)

Ну и там еще еще много всякого по мелочи - настройка каждого компа для более быстрой работы. Думаю, информацию в сети на эту тему найти можно :)

Comment: 1. почитатайте инфу по адресации в локальной сети. адреса, оканчивающиеся на 0 (ноль) указывают целую подсеть и не могут выделяться для конкретной машины - это широковещательный адрес. По-нормальному строим сеть на основе адресации 192.168.x.x, начальные 29 номеров (начиная с 1) оставляем за техническими адресами, пользователям даем начиная с 30-го.  При выделении локальной подсети размерностью 192.168.х.х/24 Вам 254 адресов хватит с лихвой.

Comment: п. 2. учительский комп - это такой же пользовательский комп, только с некоторыми привелегиями - поэтому на нем никаких сетевых серверов или сервисов не ставим !!!! Apache - это не прокси, это веб-сервер, прокси это Squid.  Для описываемых Вами вещей существует специально выделенный комп - шлюз.Веб сайт работает не на прокси!!!

Comment: п. 3 полностью согласен!  п. 4 разумно  п. 5 логично  п. 6 - если нет компов с Виндоуз - смысла самбу настраивать нет!

Comment: В школе поставить отдельный шлюз не каждый сможет. А если такой возможности нет - то приходится насиловать учительский комп. В любом случае, учительский комп неплохо бы снабдить возможностями по управлению компьютерами учеников.

Comment: Почему же не смогут? Любой старый комп уровня Cel-2000 при 512-1024 оперативы сойдет за шлюз или даже менее мощный.  Я лично, пробежал по друзьям-знакомым на предмет списываемого железа: результат в школе моего сына появились и шлюз и сервер.

Answer (score 0):

- [Настройка подключения по локальной сети в Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ivlan.net/clients/config/lan_ubuntu/)
- [Локальная сеть под Ubuntu 10.04](http://linuxforum.ru/viewtopic.php?id=8584)
- [Локальная сеть в Ubuntu. Соединяем компьютеры](http://ubuntugid.ru/?p=389)

Еще бы лучше поставить Samba и меньше проблем!

Answer (score 0):

1. Не понятно какие ОС присутствуют в классе?;
2. Если сеть из Линукс-машин для чего рекомендуется Самба? Для Линух сети лучше использовать ее родную nfs.;
3. Предоставьте более подробные данные о сети и желаемых результатах.

Answer (score 0):

Объедените их в подсеть. Пропишите айпишники  и тд